# This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store

Tags: asp.net-core

Estoy intentado ejecutar una api realizada en net core 2. He instalado el netcoresdk pero cuando intento ejecutar me sale el siguiente error:

> An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest
>   (ApiCasalSajumabavi.deps.json) was not found:
>       package: 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery', version: '2.0.1'
>       path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.dll'   This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the
>   application was published using the following target manifest files:
>       aspnetcore-store-2.0.3.xml

He copiado también la carpeta store desde /usr/share/dotnet/store y la carpeta 
/usr/share/dotnet/additionalDeps en el directorio donde esta publicada la api y
sigue sin funcionar. No sé que más hacer. Cualquier ayuda viene bien. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Respondo a mi pregunta.

El problema era una diferencia de versiones entre los paquetes proporcionados por el netcoresdk de microsoft (presentes en /usr/share/dotnet/store en ubuntu 16.04.03)
y los paquetes requeridos por la web api al tener instalado el paquete nuget
Microsoft.AspNetCoreAll en su versión más reciente.

Lo he resuelto haciendo un downgrade de este último paquete a la versión 2.0.0.

Nota: No es necesario copiar la carpeta store, ni ninguna otra, en la carpeta donde esté publicado el proyecto

Comment: Puedes marcar como aceptada esta respuesta, así le ayudas al sitio a mantener la buena salud (% de preguntas resueltas). Saludos :D